# Is there a way to always supprress desktop notifications in catkin tools?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With catkin tools, I used the `catkin build` command to build a workspace. When finished building, it displays a desktop notification that looks like this:

[image: image description]

I know that the option `--no-notify` can be used to suppress notifications each time I build, but I'd like to suppress them more permanently so that I don't have to specify `--no-notify` every time I build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265048/is-there-a-way-to-always-supprress-desktop-notifications-in-catkin-tools?/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably do this using [verb aliasing](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/verb_customization.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1